Using a 555 Timer to Connect to An Asynchronous Counter in Proteus
I'm trying to drive a binary asynchronous counter via the following setup though usually if I see binary counters they are connected to a 'CLK' source of some sort. In an ordinary case, the circuit should work having LEDs light in sequence, for testing purposes, how do I fix my 555 timer setup as I assume the NE555 timer is misconfigured.
[EDIT]
On running No LEDS light up, not even D1, where D2-D4 should light on certain intervals, please assist me as I'm looking for D1 to light up to test the output sequence of from the counter [U1]. Also is the 555 timer set to One Shot mode due to the trigger open for a single active low?


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I've edited my post, under [EDIT], integrally, I'm looking at why D1 won't light up.

You should add a resistor ( ~ 330 Ohm) serial with each LED ...

Made with microcap v12
You should add one resistor (500 Ohm) serial with the LED.
You should also add a 1k Ohm (for example) resistor between 10k Ohm and the capacitor.
Otherwise, it is ok ...

